# set cursor after append into contentEditable div by jQuery

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

i have div with smiles and contenteditable div:

```
<div id="smiles">
    <img src="/img/smile/acute.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/aggressive.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/bad.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/biggrin.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/blum1.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/blush.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/boredom.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/bye.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/clapping.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/congratulate.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/cool.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/cray.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/dance.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/dance2.gif">
</div>
<div contenteditable="false" unselectable="true" style="disabled:true" id="message_text"></div>
```

and jQuery code:

```
$("#smiles").on('click', 'img', function () {
    if ($('#message_text').prop("contentEditable") == 'true') {
        $('#message_text').append($(this).clone()).focus();
    }
});
```

after appending cursor stay on before appended smile, but i need set it after

Answer (score 0):

**JS pure solution**

You can do that by using those classes [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection), [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) 
and using method `setStartAfter` to navigate the cursor

```
let range = document.createRange()
let sel = window.getSelection()  
let smile = document.getElementById('smile')
range.setStartAfter(smile.childNodes[smile.childNodes.length -1 ])
range.collapse(true)
sel.removeAllRanges()        
sel.addRange(range)
```

You have to create new range because it's broken after contenteditable new input